# How can I make Arrayformula with row()

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a simple formula which is:

`=Row()-1`

How can I make it into Arrayformula?

The one I tried does not work =Arrayformula(Row()-1)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)-1)
```

or

```
=SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A),1,0,1)
```

[image]